# How to show views or data for specific roles in JHipster application

Tags: angularjs, roles, jhipster

I added a new role in my JHipster application. I can assign the role to users and can use the new "has-authority" ("has-role" in older versions) tag to restrict access for users with different roles. But how to restrict like menu entries for serveral roles?
I tried "has-authirity="ROLE_X ROLE_Y" and "has-authirity="ROLE_X | ROLE_Y" but none of them is working. Is there a way to specify more than one role/authority or do I really need to double to code for each role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In authority.directive.js, you can see that the directive to use is `has-any-authorithy` and that it uses `Principal.hasAnyAuthority()` which takes **an array of strings** as argument. This is what you should pass to the directive.